# vba excel compare 2 columns with condition for 3rd column

Tags: excel, vba

In sheet1 I have two columns:

[image]

In Sheet2 I have one column:

[image]

In Sheet3 I want to get the following result:

[image]

Arguments to get the data in Sheet3 are: Value of column A of Sheet2 equals a value in column A of Sheet1 (can be random row #) AND if it equals then value in column B of Sheet1 should be "a".

I wrote the following:

```
Sub MatchColumnsCondition()

    Dim sht1, sht2, sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim lr1, lr2, lr3 As Long
    Dim chk1, chk2 As Variant
    Dim out3 As Range
    Dim dup As Boolean
    Dim i, j

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'data to search in including condition
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'data to search from
    Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3") 'output data

    lr1 = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lr3 = sht3.Cells(sht3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set chk1 = sht1.Range("A1:A" & lr1)
    Set chk2 = sht2.Range("A1:A" & lr2)
    Set out3 = sht3.Range("A1:A" & lr3)

    For i = LBound(chk1) To UBound(chk1)
           For j = LBound(chk2) To UBound(chk2)
            If chk1(i, 1) = chk2(j, 1) And chk1.Offset(, 1) = "a" Then
                sht3.Range("A" & lr3) = chk1(i, 1)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

but I keep running into errors with it, but I don't know how to make it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to stay with your code

```
Sub MatchColumnsCondition()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
    Dim chk1 As Variant, chk2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'data to search in including condition
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'data to search from
    Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3") 'output data

    lr1 = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     chk1 = sht1.Range("A1:B" & lr1).Value
     chk2 = sht2.Range("A1:A" & lr2).Value

    For i = LBound(chk1) To UBound(chk1)
           For j = LBound(chk2) To UBound(chk2)
            If chk1(i, 1) = chk2(j, 1) And chk1(i, 2) = "a" Then
                sht3.Cells(sht3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = chk1(i, 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

where in your original code:

1)  `Dim sht1, sht2, sht3 As Worksheet`

would actually result in:

`Dim sht3 As Worksheet, sht1 As Variant, sht2 As Variant`

since unexplicitly declared variables (`Dim sht1, sht2`, ...) would be implicitly assumed as of `Variant` type

hence explicity declare all `Worksheet` type variables, like `Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet`

2) `LBound(chk1) To UBound(chk1)` and `LBound(chk2) To UBound(chk2)`

`LBound()` and `UBound()` functions accept an array as parameter.

In order to have an array out of a `Range` you have to take its `Value` property

then

- ok with `Dim chk1, chk2 As Variant`

that would result as `Dim chk1 As Variant, chk2 As Variant` and which is fine since a `Variant` is the right type we need to store a range values into

- `Set chk1 = sht1.Range("A1:A" & lr1)` turns into `chk1 = sht1.Range("A1:B" & lr1).Value`, since you don't `Set` an array and you need it to store column B values, too
- `Set chk2 = sht2.Range("A1:A" & lr1)` turns into `chk2 = sht2.Range("A1:A" & lr1).Value`
- you don't need `out3` , hence don't declare neither *Set* it

3) `Offset()` is a `Range` class property, while arrays have no methods nor properties

to get some value in 2nd column of a 2D array you use the column index like `chk1(i, 2)`

finally) `sht3.Range("A" & lr3)` would keep writing in the same cell over and over again

hence either you update lr3 (with some `lr3 = lr3 + 1` before `End If`) or you need a dynamic range reference always pointing to `sht3` column A first empty cell after last not empty one, like `sht3.Cells(sht3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

**EDIT**: added a different approach

provided (as per shown data) column B of Sheet1 have either "a"s or blank cells, then you could avoid loops and use `AutoFilter()` and `Specialcells()` methods of `Range` object, as follows (explanations in comments):

```
Sub MatchColumnsCondition2()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim chk2 As Variant

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'data to search in including condition
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'data to search from
    Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3") 'output data

    chk2 = sht2.Range("A1", sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value

    With sht1 ' reference "sheet1"
        With .Range("B1:A" & .Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) 'reference referenced sheet columns A:B range from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell row
            .Rows(1).EntireRow.Insert ' insert a "helper" row for headers
            With .Offset(-1).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1) ' reference referenced range plus added header row
                .Rows(1).Value = Array("h1", "h2") ' write dummy headers
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(chk2), Operator:=xlFilterValues ' filter referened range on its first column with sheet2 column A values
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, -1).Copy Destination:=sht3.Range("A1") ' copy referenced range second column filtered cells (skipping headers) with some constant value and paste to sheet 3 from cell A1
                .Rows(1).Delete xlUp ' delete "helper" row
            End With
       End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: helpful, thorough explanation :+)

Comment: Thanks a million, not only for fixing my code, but also for your explanation. It turns out I was closer than I thought, but the main problem was in my dim - leaving out the variables. I was under the false assumption that if you put dim and comma separate words and than end with a variable - all these would be that same variable.
The adjusted code did exactly what I had in mind.
Your second code does not work as intended if I have different data then "a" in column B of Sheet1. It would then also show that as a hit if the value in column A matches.Also

Comment: You are welcome. Yeah you were quite close, but for those three issues I pointed out. The second code would work if all unwanted cells in column B are blanks